# QML causing switch to discrete graphics

Tags: macos, qml, qt5

Using Qt 5.1 on OSX Mountain Lion, I'm noticing that my app is causing the computer to switch from built-in energy efficient graphics to the more power hungry discrete card.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Qt 5.3 it is possible by using special key in Info.plist for your Qt application.

1) To [use custom Info.plist](https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_do_i_add_a_custom_info.plist_to_my_mac_application_with_qmake), set QMAKE_INFO_PLIST variable in *.pro file.

```
# qmake will copy this file to MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = MyInfo.plist
```

By default, qmake generates generic Info.plist file, so you can use it as a template.
You can also see the [example here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/OS_X_application_without_menu_bar).

2) Then add the next key to the "dict" section of your Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    ... other keys here ...
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This key should work since Qt 5.3 (see [this commit](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/73839/)).

3) Make sure Qt will place your custom Info.plist file to the MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.

For some reason, Qt Creator won't update the Info.plist in the *.app file if it already exists. Thus, after the modifying Info.plist remove the *.app file from the build directory and rebuild the project to apply the changes.